# Почему некоторые координаты в Матрица Расстояний и Построение Маршрута yandex API, выдают ошибку

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

У меня есть код, который исправно работает для большинства координат, которые записываются в buyerCoordinates.
Но есть конкретные координаты(const buyerCoordinates = '55.639280, 37.686381'), по которым API возвращает { elements: [ { status: 'FAIL' } ] }

Если сменить их на соседние здание(const buyerCoordinates = '55.639280, 37.686381'), то все отрабатывает корректно.

мой код https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/damp-shadow-nn4ylt

Comment: Тут и веб-версия карт спотыкается — не даёт поворот направо к нужной точке. Что-то с контентом, наверное. Стоит пожаловаться из Навигатора или Карт, чтобы исправили.

Comment: @yacor проверил стандартные карты, маршрут вроде строится

Comment: Ну как же строится, если на подъездной проезд не сворачивает? https://yandex.ru/maps/-/C2rWEft https://screenshare.ru/s/N7XuXF96WrKsutcaY9Fu1C

Comment: Навигатор хотя бы выдает длину этого маршрута, API выдает только ошибку.

Comment: Они работают по разным схемам. Навигатор — продукт бесплатный, он может игнорировать часть ошибок и неточностей, вести вас немного мимо или не так. API Маршрутизатора же — продукт коммерческий, там ошибки более критично оцениваться должны. И раз нельзя проехать (пусть даже из-за ошибки в данных карты), значит нельзя — нужно выяснять причину и исправлять, а не давать бесполезный ответ, за который будет платить клиент. FAIL не должен оплачиваться.